# How to attach a bitmap to an email?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, bitmap

I have an image generated in the memory - `Bitmap bitmap;`. Can I attach that to an email without saving it to the file first?

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file_path));
```

Comment: have u found solution ?

Comment: @user3233280, no, I've stopped research how to do it.